# How to send comment in my facebook page post using graph api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to send comment in my facebook page post using graph api. Here is my code,

```
    try:
        x=graph.put_object(page, 'photos', message=msg, url=url) # It returns like {'id': '5887079443594804', 'post_id': '10039484545559233_588705678675675679394804'}
    except:
        print("Error while trying to send the midia file.")

    try:
        python_obj = json.loads(x)
        y=graph.put_object(python_obj[post_id], 'comments', message=msg)
    except:
        print("Error while trying to send the comment.")
```

I get

> Error while trying to send the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to add a comment. The correct method is

```py
graph.put_comment(object_id='post_id', message='...')
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-comment).

Edit: the response returns you a dictionary, not JSON, so `json.loads()` fails. Change it to

```py
try:
    y=graph.put_object(x['post_id'], 'comments', message=msg)
```

Comment: Thanks, my `python_obj[post_id]` not getting any value. I have `import json` in header.

Comment: Are you sure `x = graph.put_object` is working? If you're posting a photo, you can use `graph.put_photo`

Comment: `graph.put_object` is working and returns `{'id': '58874xxx6057434', 'post_id': '100394xxxx9233_5887xxxx36057434'}`

Comment: `x = x.replace("\'", "\"")` This command not working. I am on linux, python3

Comment: `x=graph.put_object(page, 'photos', message=msg, url=url)
        print(x)
        z = x.replace("\'", "\"")
        print(z)
except:
        print("Error while trying to send the media file.")
` returns `{'id': '588767262721988', 'post_id': '100394xxxx1559233_588767xxx721988'}
Error while trying to send the media file.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243743/discussion-between-abhinav-mathur-and-bsde).